# My animations don't export correctly for game engines (fbx file)

Tags: animation, export

I was making some animations, and when i exported it to unity, this happens [YouTube video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obtHj8Hode4)

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it by making only one armature for all objects and when parenting (ctrl+P > bone) i just market "keep transform" and for the transparent gun it is just the unity default material....

sorry for bad english